# Issue using JavaScript objects in an iOS 7 UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am creating an HTML page to be run inside a UIWebView in iOS 7. When ever I try to read a JavaScript object's property, it breaks. It doesn't crash or anything, just doesn't read the property.

Here is my JS:

```
var TestObject = {};
var TestObject2 = new Object();

TestObject.title = "This is the first Title";
TestObject2["title"] = "This is the second.";

alert(TestObject.title);
alert(TestObject2.title);
```

I've tried lowercase object names, passing the property in brackets, and no difference. The alerts read "undefined".  This code works in iOS Safari, but not within the UIWebView.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how do you read the object?

Comment: with 'TestObject.title' as shown above in the alerts. I'm just using alerts here to illustrate, even without them it is still not reading the title property.

Comment: ah sorry I misunderstood, what I tought was that you were trying to read that value from the native side

Answer (score 0):

I have thousands of problems with dealing with alerts from a uiwebview. If i was you i'd send messages from a JS and catch it with a cocoa selector. try using a library like this one:
https://github.com/tcoulter/jockeyjs
and show the alert from a uialertview.

Comment: That jockey library looks interesting and I will have to check it out, that could really help me with debugging this HTML code within the WebView. However, right now my problem is mainly with reading the object properties. The alerts seem to be working as they should. Have you had issues with objects within a WebView before?